# VF Controller search logic

Tags: apex, controller, class

The following is my controller for my VF page that is going to search for certain `Super Customers`.  On every `Account` there is a field called `Super_Customer1__c`, and since `Super_Customer1__c` will often have different names than the `Account` they need visibility in searches.  Right now what I'm doing is taking in a parameter from my VF Page and pushing it to a query in which I get all of the Id's, after I get all the alias Id's it searches Account for where `Super_Customer1__c` is located. So instead of just finding the parameters I search for it returns all of my Opptys. Does anyone see anything wrong with my logic?

```
  public Map <Id, Account> getAccountAlias(String alias){
    Set<id> aliasId = new Set<id>();     
    for(Alias__c a : [SELECT Name,Super_Customer__c FROM Alias__c WHERE Super_Customer__c =: alias]){
        aliasId.add(a.Super_Customer__c);
    }
    List<Account> accountKeys = [SELECT Name, Super_Customer1__c FROM Account WHERE Super_Customer1__c IN :aliasId];        
    Map<id, Account> aMap  = new Map<id,Account>();      
    for(Account account: accountKeys){
        aMap.put(account.ID, account);
    }
    system.debug('This is aMap ' +aMap);
    return aMap;
}

public List<Opportunity> getOpps(Set<Id> accountIds){
    return [
    Select Name,StageName 
    From Opportunity 
    WHERE AccountID IN : accountIds      
    ];
    //  
}

  Public PageReference runSearch() {
         String superCustomer = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('superCustomer');

   Map<Id, Account> accountMap = getAccountAlias(superCustomer);
  if (!accountMap.isEmpty()){        
        this.optyList = this.getOpps(accountMap.keySet());
    //    this.sampList = this.getSamp(accountMap.keySet());
        // Repeat for other types
        } 

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `aliasId.add(a.Super_Customer__c);` be `aliasId.add(a.Id);`?

Comment: Go ahead and make that an answer .. lol I tried that I swear but I think I added more conditions which broke other parts of it.. Thanks for that

Comment: Yeah sometimes you just can't see a problem in your own code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't `aliasId.add(a.Super_Customer__c);` be `aliasId.add(a.Id);`?